# when do sockjs fallback to xhr streaming transport instead of websocket

Tags: websocket, websphere, spring-websocket, sockjs, ibmhttpserver

I have a simple web app, which is using websockets. 
simple webapp: 
Frontend - using sockjs, stomp
Backend - Spring 4.2.x

Frontend & Backend are packaged in the same WAR, this WAR is deployed on IBM WebSphere Application Server v9.x

When I check the Developer Tools/Web Console in chrome(61.x)/firefox(56.0, 32 bit), I see that websocket transport is not being used, it's always xhr streaming. To use the websocket transport, I have passed the transports option in sockjs, like below, but after this change the websockets stopped working.

var sockjs = new SockJS(*my url*, null, {transports: ["websocket"]});

Do we need to change any configuration on IBM WebSphere Application Server v9.x to enable websocket transport ?

Update: on tomcat/liberty servers, sample app always uses websocket transport. Only on WAS, it is using xhr streaming. Issue in WAS?

Answer (score 0):

Websocket protocol handling is on by default for Websphere v9.x

Comment: Is there any sample code from IBM using which I can test websocket transport on WAS, or is it the browser that decides the transport ?

Comment: Ideas:
1) WebSphere implements websockets to the standard websocket spec, so any spec compliant "Hello World" app should run ok.

2) https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/samples-WebSocket_Sample. The instructions are for WebSphere Liberty but straightforward to use the war in WebSphere Application Server V9.x

3) github samples: https://github.com/WASdev/sample.async.websockets

4) WebSphere Liberty has an app accelerator you can use to build a war for a WebSocket program on WebSphere Application Server V9.x: https://liberty-app-accelerator.wasdev.developer.ibm.com/start/

Comment: sample app works, but not sure why it uses xhr streaming always.

Comment: on tomcat/liberty the sample app uses websocket transport, but only on WAS it is using xhr streaming, looks like an issue in WAS.